# yaml parse error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When i run the helm install command the below line gives me the error:

```
args: [while [ 1 ]; do echo "hi" ; sleep 1; done;]
```

Error:

```
Error: YAML parse error 
converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected ',' or ']'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets have special meaning in YAML (they indicate a flow sequence, i.e. an inline array). You need to quote that scalar (string):

```yaml
args: [ 'while [ 1 ]; do echo "I am awake" ; sleep 1; done;' ]
```

...or make it a block scalar and use the literal indicator, `|`:

```yaml
args:
  - |
    while [ 1 ]; do echo "I am awake" ; sleep 1; done;
```

Both of these [produce the same JSON](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-+args%3A+%5B+%27while+%5B+1+%5D%3B+do+echo+%22I+am+awake%22+%3B+sleep+1%3B+done%3B%27+%5D%0A-+args%3A%0A++++-+%7C%0A++++++while+%5B+1+%5D%3B+do+echo+%22I+am+awake%22+%3B+sleep+1%3B+done%3B&type=json):

```json
{
  "args": [
    "while [ 1 ]; do echo \"I am awake\" ; sleep 1; done;"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @hmims Ah, it makes sense that `args` should be a sequence (array), not a scalar (string). I’ve edited my answer.